# prevent content jumping / flickering on css position change (absolute to default)

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, css-position, css-transforms

I am making a slider / carousel for a picture gallery with 6+ pictures. 3 pictures visible at a time. On next click - I gradually move 4 pictures to the left while decreasing the opacity of 1st and increasing the opacity of 4th.

When the animation finishes the pictures **sometimes** jump / flicker (independent of a browser). 
[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbergerP/mpg29res/18/) Sometimes the animation is very smooth and nothing jumps, might have to re-run 2-3 times.

**Questions:**

1. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? (I have tried setting overflow to hidden on various elements - that didn't help)
2. Is there a better approach for making such a slider? At first I tried changing display properties - 1st element from block to hidden and vice-versa but the layout would change for the time when 4 instead of 3 elements were displayed as block. I figured a workaround would be hiding the 'not in view' pictures by giving them an absolute position and 0 opacity, which works almost as desired except for the **occasional** jumping / flickering.

Any Help or tips would be greatly appreciated! :)

P.S. positioning of elements in the Fiddle was done on a wide screen - element transitions might be misaligned on diff screen sizes

**CODE**

```js
var moveLeftFadeOut = [{
    transform: 'translateX(0)',
    opacity: 1
  },
  {
    transform: 'translateX(-60px)',
    opacity: 0.1
  }
];

var moveLeftFadeIn = [{
    transform: 'translateX(0)',
    opacity: 0.1
  },
  {
    transform: 'translateX(-60px)',
    opacity: 1
  }
];

var moveLeft = [{
    transform: 'translateX(0)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translateX(-60px)'
  }
]

var ani_time = 1000;

var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("image_container");

function swap() {
  temp[1].classList.add("hidden-left");
  temp[4].classList.remove("hidden-right");
}

function myAnimation() {
  temp[1].animate(moveLeftFadeOut, ani_time);
  temp[2].animate(moveLeft, ani_time);
  temp[3].animate(moveLeft, ani_time);
  temp[4].animate(moveLeftFadeIn, ani_time);
}

function next() {
  myAnimation();
  setTimeout(swap, ani_time);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.image_container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.my_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.hidden-right {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.1;
  left: 490px;
}

.hidden-left {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.1;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="next()">
Next !
</button>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image_container hidden-left" id='zero'>
    <div class="my_image">
      0
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image_container" id='one'>
    <div class="my_image">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image_container" id='two'>
    <div class="my_image">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image_container" id='three'>
    <div class="my_image">
      3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image_container hidden-right" id='four'>
    <div class="my_image">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have two elements with an id of one (which is not allowed)

Comment: @vals changed now but that doesn't affect anything, nor am I grabbing / manipulating anything by id